# How do I get rid of these symbols from the text fields when reading a CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-unicode

Every time I open a CSV in Python, I keep seeing these weird symbols that represent the punctuation and special characters within the text fields. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
data = pd.read_csv("Test.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1") #utf-8 encoding doesn't work
data.head()
```

The column with text will have something like "Assassinâ\x80\x99s creed origins".

So I guess you're wondering how I created the csv in the first place?

Here's the code I used:

```
def updateSubs_file():
    upload_count = 0
    import csv
    location = "csvs"
    filename = "Test.csv"
    file = location + filename
    with open(file, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file: 
        a = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
        headers = ["Title","Url","Author","Score"]
        a.writerow(headers)
        for sub in subStats:
            a.writerow(subStats[sub][0])
            upload_count+=1

        print(str(upload_count) + " rows have been uploaded")

updateSubs_file()
```

So I can see there's already an encoding mismatch when creating the csv and opening but I added the encoding="" arguments initially to avoid Unicode Decode Errors. This may/may not be a factor in my issue.

Your help would be appreciated in working out what is happening to my csvs when I'm uploading/reading them in Python.

Comment: You *definitely* have issues with encodings. "utf-8 encoding doesn't work" – but you *create* the file with UTF8. So trying if another encoding makes it magically work is way, way off. Your problem lies somewhere else. (Possibly the data you are reading *before* creating that file is not UTF8. But we cannot tell for sure.)

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 *does* work.  You wrote it with UTF-8, so decode it with UTF-8.  For example, undoing the incorrect `ISO-8859-1` decoding and re-decoding with `utf8`:

```
>>> s='Assassinâ\x80\x99s creed origins'.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf8')
'Assassin’s creed origins'
```

If you are having problems decoding what you wrote with `utf8`, show the *exact* code with sample input and output to reproduce the issue.